# Usage of would in present to express past

Tags: phrase-usage

**Scenario:**

A customer said there is no issue with their phone but the applications are not working. I reported this to my supervisor.

After some time another member from my team called the customer and asked about the same issue.

Now the customer said the applications are working fine except in specific regions.

Now my supervisor asks me about the new update which he got from my team member. He thinks that the information I gave earlier was wrong.

**Question:**
Is it appropriate to say: *"They would have found it recently"* to prove that my information was true?

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of the sentence that you provided at the end of your post was a bit ambiguous. It is unclear **what** the customer found. Therefore, it might not be effective in defending you.

In order to prove that the information that you reported to your supervisor was true, you could tell him that the customer might have found a solution to his problem during the time between the phone calls to the company.

Alternatively, you can also attempt to defend yourself by saying “The information that I reported to you was correct at that time to the best of my knowledge”.